# Encountered unsupported property FilterCriteria during cdk deploy of EventSource filter

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Suddenly stopped working if I add filters, without changing anything:

```js
claLambda.addEventSource(new lambdaEventSources.DynamoEventSource(drTable, {
   startingPosition: lambda.StartingPosition.TRIM_HORIZON,
   batchSize: 5,
   retryAttempts: 0,
   bisectBatchOnError: false,
   filters: [
     lambda.FilterCriteria.filter({
       eventName: lambda.FilterRule.isEqual("INSERT"),
       dynamodb: {  NewImage: { description: { S: lambda.FilterRule.exists() } }}
     }),
   ]
}));
```

Error during deployment when filters parameter is defined:

```
UPDATE_FAILED        | AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping     | cladrLambda/DynamoDBEventSource:drBackendStackdrTable2C197F4B (cladrLambdaDynamoDBEventSourcedrBackendStackdrTable2C197F4BBAD743BC) Encountered unsupported property FilterCriteria
```

Comment: I can't find `filters` as part of the possible props ([DynamoEventSourceProps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda-event-sources.DynamoEventSourceProps.html)) for a `DynamoEventSource`, could that be what's causing the error here?

Comment: @AdamE. interesting, it's there in V2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same today, probably a hiccup on Cloudformation side? Because this morning tried again and it worked